# Cómo colocar el botón verde debajo del párrafo al lado izquierdo y darle más ancho al párrafo y/o a la rana

Tags: html, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.globalWrapper {
 width: 1024px;
 background-color: #DFAFF9;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapperMain{
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #FEF9CF;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#backgroundHeader img{
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.textoImagen{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}


#headerImage>img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 150px;
    background-image: url("imgs/header.png");
    width:20%;
    height:150px;
}

#title1{
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 10%;
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#title2{
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 10%;
 color: orange;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#bar {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #E49C32 !important;
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
}

#lorem {
 color: #432366;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 10%;
 margin-left:5px;
}

#ranaImage>img{
  padding-left: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
    right: 150px;
    background-image: url("imgs/rana.jpg");
    width: 400px;
   height:250px;
}

#parrafo{
  float:right;
  margin-left:5px;
  width: 550px;
  height:100px;
  float: right;
  text-align: justify;
}

.myButton {
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:28px;
 border:1px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:17px;
 padding:16px 31px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 1%;
}

footer {
 width: 96%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #B5B2A0;
 padding: 15px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
}

#textFooter{
 color: #4286f4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="globalWrapper">
 <div class="wrapperMain">
  <section id="header">
   <header>
    <div id="backgroundHeader">
      <img src="imgs/fondo.png" alt="fondo encabezado" title="fondo encabezado"/>
      <div id="headerImage">
       <img src="imgs/header.png" alt="loros" title="loros"/>
      </div>
      <div class="textoImagen">
       <h1 id="title1">Carlos Acevedo</h1>
      <h2 id="title2">Tecnólogo ADSI</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section>
   <div id="bar">
   </div>
   <div>
     <p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum</p>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section>
   <div class="box" id="ranaImage">
     <img src="imgs/rana.jpg" alt="rana" title="rana"/>
   </div>
   <div class="box" id="parrafo">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
   <div>
    <a href="#" class="myButton">Perspiciate</a>
   </div>
  </section>
  <footer id="textFooter">
       Copyright © 2018 <strong>All Right Reserveds</strong>
  </footer> 
 </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @zeross, hasta ahí va como la necesito, aún no acabo, entre lo que me falta está que la linea naranja quede pegada con la imagen del header ya que como se observa hay un pequeño espacio entre ellos.

Comment: Saludos @GarcíaHenry, creo que ha habido un malentendido. Lo único que he hecho ha sido editar tu pregunta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el texto del párrafo dentro de un div y el boton dentro de otro, los divs son bloques diferentes y por lo tanto te va a costar muchísimo adaptarlo, te cambio el código para que quede así:

```
<div class="box" id="parrafo">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    <a href="#" class="myButton">Perspiciate</a>
</div>
```

Así tendremos dos divs, uno con la rana y otro con el párrafo y el botón.

Acostúmbrate a usar los divs para agrupar varios elementos y no poner un solo elemento dentro de un div siempre.

El css para que este la rana a la izquierda, el párrafo a la derecha y todo ocupando todo el ancho sería así.

```
#ranaImage{
    width: 45%;
}

#ranaImage img{
    width: 100%;
}

#parrafo{
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Acabo de ver que dentro del div rana tienes un '< img >' con la rana, y en el css tienes un #rana>img donde a esa img le añades de background la misma img, no necesitas hacer esto, esa linea la puedes borrar

Comment: @@CobasESP hasta ahí va como la necesito, aún no acabo, entre lo  que me falta está que la linea naranja quede pegada con la imagen del header ya que como se observa hay un pequeño espacio entre ellos.

Comment: Pues eso será un tema de margin o padding, te recomiendo que uses el inspector y vayas viendo cada elemento por separado para ver quien esta metiendo ahi ese espacio, si no lo ves, un pequeño apaño es a la barra naranja ponerle un margin-top negativo, por ejemeplo, margin-top: -20px;